# WSAECONNABORTED when using recv for the second time

Tags: networking, winsock

I am writing a 2D multiplayer game consisting of two applications, a console server and windowed client. So far, the client has a FD_SET which is filled with connected clients, a list of my game object pointers and some other things. In the main(), I initialize listening on a socket and create three threads, one for accepting incoming connections and placing them within the FD_SET, another one for processing objects' location, velocity and acceleration and flagging them (if needed) as the ones that have to be updated on the client. The third thread uses the send() function to send update info of every object (iterating through the list of object pointers). Such a packet consists of an operation code, packet size & the actual data. On the client I parse it, by reading first 5 bytes (the opcode and packet size) which are received correctly, but when I want to read the remaining part of the packet (since I now know the size of it), I get a WSAECONNABORTED (error code 10053). I've read about this error, but can't see why it occurs in my application. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error means the system closed the socket. This could be because it detected that the client disconnected, or because it was sending more data than you were reading.

A parser for network protocols typcally needs a lot of work to make it robust, and you can't tell how much data you will get in a single read(), e.g. you may get more than your operation code and packet size in the first chunk you read, you might even get less (e.g. only the operation code). Double check this isn't happening in your failure case.

Comment: I made sure that the first recv() gets me exactly 5 bytes. The first recv() always works as expected, although the second recv() always fails with a 10053 error. At first the server was pumping many packets in short periods of time, but to make sure it wasn't the reason the recv() function was failing, I changed it so that only one packet per 10 seconds was sent, thus it's not what's causing the problem.